# when editing script elements code, should it be edited with textContent or innerHTML? or something else?

Tags: javascript, dom

for example,

```js
function browserInjectCode(code){
    let ele=document.createElement("script");
    ele.textContent=code;
    document.head.appendChild(ele);
}
browserInjectCode("console.log(\"js code may contain html elements\");\n\/\/ <this><is><a><comment>");
```

given that javascript may contain html elements, i wonder, should code in script-elements be edited with .innerHTML or .textContent  ? should the above function use `ele.textContent=code;` or `ele.innerHTML=code;` ? is there even a difference?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

### Differences from innerHTML

> innerHTML returns HTML, as its name indicates. Sometimes people use
> innerHTML to retrieve or write text inside an element, but textContent
> has better performance because its value is not parsed as HTML.
> Moreover, using textContent can prevent XSS attacks.

You can use either, but it depends on your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, innerHTML is meant to keep the html qualities of the code (as the name suggests), including html tags within your code (like keeping the functionality "strong" in a "p" tag). Example: If you had the following div;

```
<div id="hi"><strong>hi    hello</strong></div>
```

and got the innerHTML value it would give you the following;

```
<strong>hi    hello</strong>
```

innerContent would not keep an html element's value but would keep the content of the div;

```
hi    hello
```

Another Javascript tool called innerText would simplify further by giving you the text but would not give you the extra space put between the text;

```
hi hello
```

I think that if you are adapting the contents of a script tag it would make the most sense to use innerContent. I hope this is helpful. If you want a more detailed explanation, go the following link; https://medium.com/better-programming/whats-best-innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-textcontent-903ebc43a3fc.